# Access to Apple's built in Icons?

Tags: ios, icons

Is it possible to use Apple's build in home screen icons in my app without finding them on the internet and adding them to my resources. I am asking because I wan't to keep the app to lowest size possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple is very picky about how their trademarks are used, if you want to see your app hit the app store, I suggest not using any Apple trademarks, including their homescreen icons.

That being said, I am pretty sure there is no way to access the homescreen icons without jailbreaking your device.

So... no, it is not possible.

Adding your own icons shouldn't add much to the size of your app though - I say add your own Icons and consider it an acceptable tradeoff between app size and getting accepted on the app store :)

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, you must provide your own Application and App Store Icon.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: I wasn't talking about icons but just like for a UIImageView in my app, and then getting the file path to the image from the OS.

Comment: Even the file path isn't available unfortunately.