# Sending pictures to iMovie iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios

The iPhoto app for the iPhone has a feature (it is part of the Share options) that lets you send one or more photos the the iMovie iPhone application.

Does anyone know how such a feature (send photos to the iMovie app from another app) can be implemented? It seems to be using URL Schemas but I can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: Have you seen any apps that actually do this, or do you just have to save the photos to the camera roll and open them with iMovie?

Comment: I think most of this is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546574/using-apple-icons-with-ios-6 -- the question is just, if iMovie actually will register for your movie resource. Can't try that now, because I haven't got my Mac with me.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the NSURL of the image you want to share. If you're image is just in memory, you can save the image somewhere and then use that URL.

```
NSURL *imageURL = /* URL of your image */
```

Now create an UIDocumentInteractionController with the method:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController = 
     [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageURL];
```

That's it. You can go ahead and present your documentInteractionController with any of these methods:

```
– presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:
– presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:
– presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:
– presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:
– dismissMenuAnimated:
```

So now a popover will show up, listing **all the apps that are willing to use your image (including iMovie if installed).**

If you want to find out more about UIDocumentInteractionController, go here: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The thing is that when i do that with an image most of the image related applications are suggested, but not iMovie. That is why I was asking if there is any specific trick for reaching iMovie. As I mentioned, iPhoto seems to do it, but may be it is an internal Apple trick.

Comment: If iMovie only shows up in iPhoto, then Apple is obviously using some private API to do this so as to get more people to buy iPhoto.

Answer (score 0):

use [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1) :

Right from the doc:

> To prompt the user only to open the file in another app, call the **presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:** or **presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:** method.

or

> To prompt the user with a set of options, including an option to open the file in another app, call the **presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:** or **presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:** method.

Here is how you can do it:

1. Register your **first** app to be able to handle your preferred image file type
2. At your **second** app, implement the methods I stated about from UIDocumentInteractionController. So it will prompt an option for the user to send pic to the **first** app. [Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1) for this.
3. At your **first** app, implement this method:

   `-(BOOL)application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`

   to open the picture that is transferred from the first app. The pictures will be stored at `Documents/Inbox`. Then, you can now happily use the picture in your first app.